# ember.js saving a model deletes elements from UI

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have inherited an Ember.js application built on top of a Rails API. This was originally running the following:

```
Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember.js
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember.js
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.10.2
```

but these have been updated to the following:

```
Ember      : 1.7.1+pre.f095a455 ember.js
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.10+canary.30d6bf849b ember.js
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 ember.js
```

using the ember-rails gem.

I have an action bound to an UI element to create a new model and insert this into the page within a row of items. This works in the previous legacy app but not in the new app.

When the action button is clicked the new model is created passing in the row object and initial section data. FYI, This is in the sections_controller.js file, not the route.

```
_createSection: function(row, new_section_data){
new_section_data.row      = row;
new_section_data.width    = this.getNewSectionWidth(row);
new_section_data.position = this.getNewSectionPosition(row);

var store = this.get('store');
var new_section = store.createRecord('section', new_section_data);
new_section.save();

new_section.one('didCreate', function(){
  new_section.set('set_as_selected', true);
}.bind(this, new_section))

return new_section;
},
```

The issue occurs as soon as the store.createRecord() method is called. The UI layout actually removes the row block element into which the item should be placed and it doesnt return or update with the freshly inserted item, which it should.

I can see from the Ember chrome plugin that the raw data is being stored in the store but not necessarily being sent to the remote DB using the API. The main issue though is the loss of the UI once the record is created.

I am unable to show too much of the code but does anyone have any idea why this may be happening? The didCreate method does run, but losing the UI is a big issue. I'm fairly new to Ember and so updating a legacy app with this many changes between Ember data alone is proving a little tricky.

Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Would need to see the template. Also, may not be a problem, but I'd switch from the `one.('didCreate'...` to `then` on the `save`. Then you could also provide an error handler to easily see if something is going wrong with the save.

Comment: As it turns out I think there is a different issue relating directly to the model at fault here (potentially). When I save a new section item the row disappears from the UI because it also disappears from the local data store (using the Ember Chrome plugin you literally see it vanish). The row model has a hasMany relationship to the section model, but I'm still confused by saving one would delete the other.

Comment: I have updated the issue in a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585922/ember-rails-model-relationship and will close this one down.